# cannot install django-filebrowser app

Tags: django, django-filebrowser

I did exactly as it says here: http://readthedocs.org/docs/django-filebrowser/en/latest/quickstart.html#quickstart (only used easy_install instead of pip)

it seems that I get an import error when trying to connect to admin interface:

```
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/
Django Version:     1.3
Exception Type:     ImportError
Exception Value:    

No module named sites

Exception Location:     c:\workspace\expedeat\..\expedeat\urls.py in <module>, line 5
Python Executable:  c:\Tools\Python26\python.exe
Python Version:     2.6.4
```

the import the exception comes from is: `from filebrowser.sites import site` in urls.py

Also testing filebrowser fails with this message:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
.......F......
======================================================================
FAIL: test_directory (filebrowser.tests.settings.SettingsTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Tools\Python26\lib\site-packages\django_filebrowser-3.3.0-py2.6.egg\filebrowser\tests\set
tings.py", line 29, in test_directory
    self.assertEqual(os.path.exists(os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT,DIRECTORY)), 1)
AssertionError: False != 1

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 14 tests in 0.008s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

I must be doing something wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I also noticed that when pressing the `browse` button on the windows popup of `insert/edit image` of the tinyMCE button panel I get this javascript error: `Error: f is undefined
Code: http://localhost:8000/static/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_src.js
line: 11981`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the sites.py module does not exist in version you are using, so the error message is correct.

the installation doc you are using is for version 3.4. The pip install is 3.3. The difference being in the `urls.py`

3.4

```
from filebrowser.sites import site
urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url(r'^admin/filebrowser/', include(site.urls)),
)
```

3.3

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^admin/filebrowser/', include('filebrowser.urls')),
)
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. However I still get the same test error and I am not sure if it works properly. I also load grappelli and tinyMCE apps (which work) and when I try to upload an image through tinyMCE's `insert/edit image` button the `browse` button in the popup window does not open the file explorer. is it my MEDIA_ROOT setting?

Comment: check if you have the settings.py variable ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/'. this has been deprecated but filebrowser seems to need it.

Comment: I modified my ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX according to grappelli tutorial: http://readthedocs.org/docs/django-grappelli/en/latest/quickstart.html

Answer (score 3):

The test fails because it's looking for a non-existing directory.

To find out what directory it's looking for, do the following:

```
% python ./manage.py shell 
>>> from django.conf import settings 
>>> import filebrowser.settings 
>>> filebrowser.settings.MEDIA_ROOT
'/srv/repositories/project/media'
>>> filebrowser.settings.DIRECTORY 
'uploads/'
```

Based on the output, you know what directory it's looking for, /srv/repositories/project/media/uploads in this example. Create the directory and you should be one step further on your way.

Answer (score 2):

Using the "FILEBROWSER_" prefix, you can supply configuration for the filebrowser app.

I use the following in my settings.py :

```
FILEBROWSER_DIRECTORY = MEDIA_ROOT
```